# Set step in CreateUserWizard by parameters in QueryString in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, createuserwizard

I have createuserwizard control which has 4 steps. When some parameters exists in qeurystring, I want to set them for contols in step 0 and then set activeindex to next step. I do it like this:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["from"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["to"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["seek"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["livein"]))
            {
                ((DropDownList)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("ddlGender")).SelectedValue = Request["seek"];
                ((TextBox)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("txtAgeFrom")).Text = Request["from"];
                ((TextBox)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("txtAgeTo")).Text = Request["to"];
                ((DropDownList)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("ddlLive")).SelectedValue = Request["livein"];

                RegisterUser.ActiveStepIndex = 1;
            }
        }
```

This works and set current step to correct step but the problem is "Previous" button does not work and it does not go to step 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the *Previous* button is clicked on the Wizzard control in ASP.NET there are two events which fire, in this order:

1) `PreviousButtonClick`

2) `ActiveStepChanged`

My suggestion is - put break points in these two events and make sure both are executed when you click *Previous*.

Additionally, if you have any code inside the two event handlers which I've just mentioned make sure that they do not reset the `ActiveStepIndex`